# How to find out phonenumbers based on (chess) knight moves

Tags: python-3.x, dynamic-programming

So basically in this problem we have a knight (from chess) and a keypad from a phone. Using the possible moves for knight (i.e. 'L' shape) we have to find the total count of phone numbers that can possibly be made of given length n.

```
class Solution:
    def knightDialer(self, n: int) -> int:
        dp = {}
        def traverse(r, c, length):
            if r < 0 or r > 3 or c < 0 or c > 2 or keypad[r][c] == 0:
                return 0
            if length == n:
                return 1
            if (r,c,length) in dp:
                return dp[(r,c,length)]
            row = [-2,-2,-1,1,2,2,1,-1]
            col = [-1,1,2,2,1,-1,-2,-2]
            count = 0
            for pos in range(8):
                nrow = r+row[pos]
                ncol = c+col[pos]
                count += traverse(nrow, ncol, length + 1)
            dp[(r,c,length)] = count
            return count
        keypad = [[1,1,1],[1,1,1],[1,1,1],[0,1,0]]
        ans = 0
        for r in range(4):
            for c in range(3):
                ans += traverse(r,c,1)
        return ans%(10^9+7)
```

So I've tried an approach wherein I check if the position of the knight is valid or not. If the traversal reaches required length then I return `1`, indicating I successfully got a phone number. I' using a dictionary for memoization.

So yes, basically looking for valid moves till I reach length `n`.
This approach is working for few test cases. But not able to figure out what is going wrong.

```
Test case :  n = 3131 
Output = 4 
Expected Output = 136006598
```

Thanks for the help in advance. P.S I am new to StackOverflow so pls pardon incase if my presentation is not correct.

Comment: You'll have to add more details/info: "*his approach is working for few test cases. But not able to figure out what is going wrong.*" - What is going wrong? Why is it working for some of the cases

Comment: It would be faster for you to set up a list of all possible destinations from each starting position.  There are only 2 possible moves for each button except for 4 and 6, which have 3.

Comment: I don't see how memoization helps here.  `length` is monotonically increasing, so you will never use one of the memoized values.

Comment: @TimRoberts Thank you for the input, actually makes sense for me now.

Comment: @DarkBee took a note of these and thanks for the edit